# Size of controls when minimized (GetWindowPlacement)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi

It seems that GetWindowPlacement can only return the size of a minimized **window**.

Is it possible to get the size of the individual **controls inside that window** when the window is minimized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WINDOWPLACEMENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632611%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).rcNormalPosition is defined as:

> The window's coordinates when the window is in the restored position.

To get the current size use the [GetWindowRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function. There is also an interesting [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/10/370445.aspx) by Raymond Chen on this topic.

The following program gives correct size of a control in a minimized window:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct RECT
{
     public int L;
     public int T;
     public int R;
     public int B;
}

static class Program
{
    void Main()
    {
        RECT r;
        bool result = GetWindowRect(0x00120E34, out r);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} {2} {3} {4}", r.T, r.L, r.B, r.R);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    extern bool GetWindowRect(int hwnd, out RECT lpRect);
}
```

> True: -31948 -31335 -31923 -30761

Comment: maybe my question is unclear. This is not what I was looking for. I try to rephrase my question

Comment: What did you try and what where the results?

Comment: I tried with a control and the result is l:-31966, r:-31966, t:-31686, b:-31686 => which means width and height are 0. Did you pass the handle of a control or the handle of a window?

Comment: The control. In your case, the width and height of the control just might be zero, if the window changes layout when it is minimized.

Comment: Hmm that would be weird. I'll verify that in a test app later. Thanks.

Comment: You were right all the way. Our 3rd party window framework resizes the control to (0,0) on minimize. Who does that? Argh!.

Answer (score 0):

What about [GetWindowRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519%28VS.85%29.aspx)? It gives you position and size.